# mysql select all rows that have no duplicates in field x

Tags: mysql

```
id   value
1    a
2    b
3    b
4    c
```

Either this is late on a friday evening, or i just have forgotten some fundamentals in MySQL.

I need to be able to pull out of the example table above everything bar any results that have duplicates in field value.

Select distinct will of course pull out once instance of 'b'. But i need no results with 'b'.

IE:

```
   1    a
   4    c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id), value
GROUP BY value
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```